# Cannot figure out double free or corruption (fasttop) error

Tags: c++, qt

The following method generates a double free or corruption (fasttop) error (on the first line) during run time. It happens randomly i.e. it might happen at the first second or the 35 second while the program is running.

```
QSharedPointer<QPixmap> Utils::loadImg(QString fileName)
{
    QPixmap *pixmap = new QPixmap(fileName);
    QSharedPointer<QPixmap> qspPixmap(pixmap);
    return qspPixmap;
}
```

This is a static method that I am calling to get the pointer (actually using smart pointers that Qt provides) of an pixmap. Once I get the smart pointer I store it to a map structure for later use. When I remove the entry from the map structure it should free the memory and it seems like that it does so.
Note that the loadImg(QString) method is called by another method that is running on its own thread (using QtConcurrent and QFuture provided by Qt).

I really cannot figure out what the problem is. The debugger shows the first line as the problematic one.

Thank for your help in advance.

Comment: Which line is the "first" one exactly?  If you're on Linux, try valgrind.

Comment: It's likely that something bad has happened well before you get to that line, but that's when the memory manager discovers the corruption. You need to work your backwards and check all the memory management up to that point.

Comment: Running your app under valgrind might help you track down the place where the heap initially got corrupted.

Comment: Hi all, by first line I mean the line where the raw pointer (not the smart pointer) is created. I am on Linux so I will try valgrind as you suggested I just do not have experience at all with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that pixmaps are implicitly shared, this method makes no sense. Pass them by value! You should also pass string arguments by const reference, unless you intend to modify them inside of your method.

You're completely free to have a `QMap<QString, QPixmap>` and treat everything as values.

If, by any chance, you're calling this method in any thread but the main thread, you're invoking undefined behavior - you should be using a `QImage` instead.

Your method should look as follows:

```
QPixmap Utils::loadImg(const QString & fileName)
{
   Q_ASSERT(QThread::currentThread() == qApp->thread());
   return QPixmap{fileName};
}
```

If you're intending to call it in arbitrary thread, you should have:

```
QImage Utils::loadImg(const QString & fileName)
{
   return QImage{fileName};
}
```

And of course in either case the method is trivial, so there's no need to use it other than to verify that you're creating pixmaps in the correct thread.

Comment: thank you for the help. Your answer have solved my problem. I understand why I should not be using the QSharedPointer since as you said the QPixmap and QImage are implicitly shared. However, I do not understand why when calling the method from the main thread you can/should return a QPixmap while when not calling it from the main thread you have to return a QImage instead. Can you please explain that. Thank you.

Comment: `QPixmap` cannot be used outside of the main thread. That's all. You don't have to use `QPixmap` at all: the default graphics backend is the raster backend, and all pixmaps are, internally, `QImages` with a screen-compatible format. So you might as well use a `QImage` to begin with. There's no speed advantage **of any sort** for `QPixmap` on the raster backend. None. You only ever need to use it to interop with native code - even then it's a maybe.